# How can I change the query to make result not equal to NULL

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I use LINQ to the entity in my project.
At some point I fetch data from database:

```
 int vectorLayerId = 5;
 int pointFeatId = 10;

 var RealValue = x.VectorLayer_FieldsValue
                  .Where(f=>f.FeatIdPointFeatures == vectorLayerId && f.VectorLayerFieldsId == pointFeatId)
                  .Select(v => new { v.Id, v.FieldValue })
                  .FirstOrDefault()
```

if in my database doesn't exist record that associated with a filter the RealValue object is set to NULL.
While I need  RealValue to be all properties Id zero and FieldValue property empty if the record that associated with the filter not exists.

How can I change the query above to make RealValue not to be NULL and properties Id and FieldValue zero and empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
int vectorLayerId = 5;
int pointFeatId = 10;

 var RealValue = x.VectorLayer_FieldsValue
                  .Where(f=>f.FeatIdPointFeatures == vectorLayerId && f.VectorLayerFieldsId == pointFeatId)
                  .Select(v => new { v.Id, v.FieldValue })
                  .FirstOrDefault() ?? new { Id = 0, FieldValue = "0"};
```

This uses the null-coalescing operator (??) to return an anonymous type with a property Id and FieldValue (both set to 0) when the Linq query returns null.

Incidentally, if you're using C# 7, you could also have your Linq query create a Tuple instead of an anonymous type, which might be easier if you need to return it in a function or something like that:

```
int vectorLayerId = 5;
int pointFeatId = 10;

 var RealValue = x.VectorLayer_FieldsValue
                  .Where(f=>f.FeatIdPointFeatures == vectorLayerId && f.VectorLayerFieldsId == pointFeatId)
                  .Select(v => (v.Id, v.FieldValue))
                  .FirstOrDefault() ?? (Id: 0, FieldValue: "0");
```

Comment: Thanks for post I get error :

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0019 Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type '<anonymous type: int Id, string FieldValue>' and '<anonymous type: int Id, int FieldValue>'


 when I try to use your first example

Comment: I've edited my answer, I thought FieldValue was also an int but apparently is a string. The code in the answer should now work,

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `DefaultIfEmpty(defaultVal)` method as described in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=netframework-4.7.2).

```
 int vectorLayerId = 5;
 int pointFeatId = 10;

 var RealValue = x.VectorLayer_FieldsValue
                  .Where(f=>f.FeatIdPointFeatures == vectorLayerId && f.VectorLayerFieldsId == pointFeatId)
                  .Select(v => new { v.Id, v.FieldValue })
                  .DefaultIfEmpty(new { 0, "" }).Single(); // assuming that FieldValue is a string
```

Comment: I'd suggest using .Single() over .First(), just because it's clearer that there's only one element in the default return value, and because it throws an exception if there isn't (which would notify you that something happened that you didn't think of.) :)